# Upvoting inconsistencies

Tags: discussion, up-votes

It's the same community doing the upvoting on all of the questions, so I don't understand the inconsistencies.

There is one question which has four answers, one of them is mine and I think is clearly correct (of course).  So I'm not about to upvote the other answers which I think are wrong, and I can't upvote my own answer.  Yet nobody is upvoting any of them.

There is another question that someone gave a non-working answer to, and I submitted what I think is the right answer, and the non-working answer almost immediately after posting got four up-votes.  I commented on it, poked holes in it, and finally the person answering admitted that it didn't work for all conditions.  Yet, it's still sitting there at +3 (because I down-voted it).

Is this just a frustrating side-effect of effective randomness inherent in the community?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voting is imperfect. Lots of times we vote on what *looks* right — that doesn't mean it *is* right. It can be difficult for a new right answer to overcome and old wrong answer after the question is off the front page.

Ultimately the OP has the final say by selecting an "accepted" answer. You'll find that if you answer is accepted, it will quickly gain upvotes even if it is not already the highest scoring answer.

Answer (score 1):

Voting is especially erratic on the more niche topics, so you have to really examine the answers carefully instead of just going with the highest voted.  I just try to make things better by voting appropriately on my niche topics, and hope for more participation in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes people will upvote and forget. They don't come back to the question to re-examine other possible answers.

You can @comment then to notify them about the question (if they left a comment or authored a question) or edit the question (provided you have the rep) to bump it back up and let other people see it.